# Sync multiple email accounts at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

We have an app that allows us to signup using one email id and can add/ link another email id. When we enter the home page after signup, it should show the teams/challenges created using the first email id on the top and the teams created using the second email id on the bottom. We are thinking of using firebase for backend. Is it possible to have two email ids active at the same time?

Comment: This doesn't sound like you have two email ids active at the same time. It sounds like you want a user who is signed in to be able to select other users to add to their team? Is that correct? If so, can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You must go outside BaaS, particularly Firebase, as you have mentioned. You can consider making your own backend server for that feature.

What Firebase can provide you is the ability to have a **single email address** connected to different sign-in methods.

ref: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9134820?hl=en&ref_topic=6386702

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebase Authentication to sign in users, then no, it's not possible to have two accounts signed in to a single device at a time.  If you sign in a second account, then the first one will be automatically signed out.

If you want to "link" two accounts in such a way that they can query each others' data, you're going to have to establish that relationship in your database or custom claims, and use that in security rules to allow shared access to data.